# obtener actionViewClass de menuitem android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, nullpointerexception, navigationview, linearlayout

Estoy tratando de hacer un menuitem personalizado pero al intentar obtener una propiedad de la clase personalizada me da `java.lang.NullPointerException`

este es mi codigo:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
     android:id="@+id/nav_view"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
     app:menu="@menu/main.xml" />
```

**main.xml**

```
<menu>
    
      <item
           android:id="@+id/nav_newversion"
           tools:ignore="MenuTitle"
           app:actionViewClass="com.package.meteorocorte.customitem" />
</menu>
```

**customitem.java**

```
public class customitem extends LinearLayout {
    TextView text=new TextView(getContext());

    public customitem(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOrientation(VERTICAL);
        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        setPadding(0,12,0,12);
        text.setText(("hola"));
        text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        addView(text);
    }

    public TextView getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
MenuItem item=((NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view)).getMenu().getItem(0);
item.setVisible(true);
TextView text= ((customitem) item.getActionView()).getText();//aqui me da java.lang.NullPointerException
```

y si se preguntaronn si servia la personalización les dejo la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es correcto lo que realizas, recuerda que el item debe ser el primer elemento dentro de @menu/main.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es correcto la mayoría de lo que realizas, obtienes el elemento del `NavigationView`, esto debería funcionar sin problema:

```
MenuItem item=((NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view)).getMenu().getItem(0);
TextView text= ((customitem) item.getActionView()).getText();
```

Pero es super importante que en el archivo del menu `main.xml` el elemento sea en verdad el primero (indice 0)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_newversion"
        tools:ignore="MenuTitle"
        app:actionViewClass="com.package.meteorocorte.customitem" />


</menu>
```

y la clase `customitem` en verdad se encuentre en el paquete: "com.package.meteorocorte", asegura estas dos cosas y te aseguro realizaras sin problema lo que deseas.